# No module.a output on build

Tags: ios, trigger.io

When I build by custom native module, xCode reports success and runs in inspector, but no module.a is produced. I've looked in many locations and searched all directories, but no luck. 
I changed ForgeInspector target to UniversalForgeModule. Tried changing to release build. Still no module.a in a build folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two key steps for any other XCode beginners out there:

1. You can't just change the drop down in the Build Window. Choose `Product > Scheme > UniversalForgeModule`.
2. Build using `Product > Build For > Profiling` to get a Release build that contains the custom script that produces module.a